# When is z-index not obeyed?

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, extjs, google-maps-api-3

I'm working on a pretty complex web application in Ext with Google maps API v3. I have a large selection of markers with labels (using class MarkerWithLabel version 1.1.5) and I use MarkerManager.

The problem is that I have a class of markers (waypoints) that I want *behind* my other markers when they are overlapping.

I've tried to force the z-index down below that of the other markers, and according to the Firebug DOM inspector, I have succeeded. However, they still appear in front. This is true in FF and Chrome (I don't need to test other browsers).

I've been through the HTML generated by the DOM viewer very closely. The odd thing is that Firebug is showing the relevant nodes faded, as if they were hidden, but they are not.

The following is copied and pasted from the DOM inspector (with identifying info deleted). The waypoint marker is the one with z-index 100/101.

```
<div style="z-index: 105; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
<div class="markerselected" style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; opacity: 0.01; margin-left: 2px; margin-top: 2px; left: 554px; top: 271px; z-index: 1000001; display: block;" onselectstart="return false;" ondragstart="return false;"  >aaaaa</div>
<div class="markerLabel" style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; opacity: 0.01; margin-left: 2px; margin-top: 2px; left: 565px; top: 279px; z-index: 280; display: block;" onselectstart="return false;" ondragstart="return false;"  >bbbbb</div>
<div class="markerLabel" style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; opacity: 0.01; margin-left: 2px; margin-top: 2px; left: 544px; top: 277px; z-index: 278; display: block;" onselectstart="return false;" ondragstart="return false;"  >ccccc</div>
<div class="markerLabelWP" style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; opacity: 0.01; margin-left: 2px; margin-top: 2px; left: 570px; top: 259px; z-index: 101; display: none;" onselectstart="return false;" ondragstart="return false;"  >aaaaaa</div>
<div class="gmnoprint" style="width: 30px; height: 30px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; left: 535px; top: 235px; z-index: 265; opacity: 0.01; cursor: pointer;" >
<div class="gmnoprint" style="width: 30px; height: 30px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; left: 539px; top: 241px; z-index: 1000000; opacity: 0.01; cursor: pointer;" >
<div class="gmnoprint" style="width: 30px; height: 30px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; left: 550px; top: 249px; z-index: 279; opacity: 0.01; cursor: pointer;" >
<div class="gmnoprint" style="width: 30px; height: 30px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; left: 529px; top: 247px; z-index: 277; opacity: 0.01; cursor: pointer;" >
<div class="gmnoprint" style="width: 32px; height: 32px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; left: 554px; top: 227px; z-index: 100; opacity: 0.01; cursor: pointer;" >
</div>
```

Writing all this out gave me some ideas, but I still haven't solved it. I wonder if all the nested divs with their own z-indexes is the problem??

Comment: PS the incorrect-looking nesting is just because of the way the dom inspector copies/pastes

Comment: SOLVED: the issue arose - apparently - because the icons on the important markers were made of two parts, marker and shadow. The waypoint was just a marker, so it was obscuring the shadow part of the main markers regardless of how I changed the z-index. I therefore made the waypoint markers transparent and used a shadow as the "pin". This fixed it for me. I still can't explain the z-index phenomenon, but it works now so I don't care!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For better understanding z-index: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Understanding_CSS_z-index (7 links inside)

Answer (score 4):

Pete, I also struggeled with `z-index` from time to time when it just did not seem to work.

The problem was mostly solved when adding `float` or `position` to the element as well. As you probably do not want to use `float`, a simple `position:relative` should do it...

Comment: Thanks Helmut. For anyone else with this problem be sure to distinguish between images and BG images because the map and markers are built with many parts!

Answer (score 0):

Container on z-index 105 with content on various z-index. So the children are bouncing off the params of the parent.

Comment: Thanks MrJinPengyou. I'm not certain that this is the solution. Have a read of the link Rustam posted above.